# BGL adjacency_list<listS, listS>::vertex_descriptor evaluates to void*

Tags: c++, dictionary, boost, stl, boost-graph

`boost::graph_traits<graph_type>::vertex_descriptor> vertex_map_type` evaluates to `void*`
 when using `boost::listS` for `VertexListS`

This following code doesn't compile. However using `vecS` instead of `listS` works.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <map>
#include <list>
#include <boost/uuid/uuid.hpp>
#include <boost/uuid/uuid_io.hpp>
#include <boost/graph/adjacency_list.hpp>
#include <boost/graph/adj_list_serialize.hpp>
#include <boost/archive/binary_oarchive.hpp>
#include <boost/archive/binary_iarchive.hpp>
#include <boost/serialization/map.hpp>
#include <boost/uuid/uuid_io.hpp>
#include <boost/uuid/uuid_serialize.hpp>

typedef boost::adjacency_list<
    boost::listS,
    boost::listS, // << ------ vecS works but listS or setS doesn't !!
    boost::bidirectionalS> graph_type;
typedef std::map<boost::uuids::uuid, typename boost::graph_traits<graph_type>::vertex_descriptor> vertex_map_type;

int main(){
    graph_type graph;
    vertex_map_type map;
    std::ofstream stream("archive");
    boost::archive::binary_oarchive archive(stream);
    archive << graph;
    archive << map;
    return 0;
}
```

Doesn't compile due to `void*`

```
$ g++ graph.cpp -o graph -lboost_graph -lboost_serialization
In file included from /usr/include/boost/archive/detail/interface_oarchive.hpp:23:0,
                 from /usr/include/boost/archive/detail/common_oarchive.hpp:22,
                 from /usr/include/boost/archive/basic_binary_oarchive.hpp:34,
                 from /usr/include/boost/archive/binary_oarchive_impl.hpp:23,
                 from /usr/include/boost/archive/binary_oarchive.hpp:21,
                 from graph.cpp:9:
/usr/include/boost/archive/detail/oserializer.hpp: In instantiation of ‘static void boost::archive::detail::save_pointer_type<Archive>::invoke(Archive&, TPtr) [with TPtr = void*; Archive = boost::archive::binary_oarchive]’:
/usr/include/boost/archive/detail/oserializer.hpp:525:24:   required from ‘void boost::archive::save(Archive&, T&) [with Archive = boost::archive::binary_oarchive; T = void* const]’
/usr/include/boost/archive/detail/common_oarchive.hpp:69:40:   required from ‘void boost::archive::detail::common_oarchive<Archive>::save_override(T&, int) [with T = void* const; Archive = boost::archive::binary_oarchive]’
/usr/include/boost/archive/basic_binary_oarchive.hpp:75:7:   required from ‘void boost::archive::basic_binary_oarchive<Archive>::save_override(const T&, int) [with T = void*; Archive = boost::archive::binary_oarchive]’
/usr/include/boost/archive/binary_oarchive_impl.hpp:51:9:   required from ‘void boost::archive::binary_oarchive_impl<Archive, Elem, Tr>::save_override(T&, int) [with T = void* const; Archive = boost::archive::binary_oarchive; Elem = char; Tr = std::char_traits<char>]’
/usr/include/boost/archive/detail/interface_oarchive.hpp:63:9:   required from ‘Archive& boost::archive::detail::interface_oarchive<Archive>::operator<<(T&) [with T = void* const; Archive = boost::archive::binary_oarchive]’
/usr/include/boost/serialization/nvp.hpp:79:9:   [ skipping 52 instantiation contexts, use -ftemplate-backtrace-limit=0 to disable ]
/usr/include/boost/archive/detail/oserializer.hpp:525:24:   required from ‘void boost::archive::save(Archive&, T&) [with Archive = boost::archive::binary_oarchive; T = const std::map<boost::uuids::uuid, void*>]’
/usr/include/boost/archive/detail/common_oarchive.hpp:69:40:   required from ‘void boost::archive::detail::common_oarchive<Archive>::save_override(T&, int) [with T = const std::map<boost::uuids::uuid, void*>; Archive = boost::archive::binary_oarchive]’
/usr/include/boost/archive/basic_binary_oarchive.hpp:75:7:   required from ‘void boost::archive::basic_binary_oarchive<Archive>::save_override(const T&, int) [with T = std::map<boost::uuids::uuid, void*>; Archive = boost::archive::binary_oarchive]’
/usr/include/boost/archive/binary_oarchive_impl.hpp:51:9:   required from ‘void boost::archive::binary_oarchive_impl<Archive, Elem, Tr>::save_override(T&, int) [with T = std::map<boost::uuids::uuid, void*>; Archive = boost::archive::binary_oarchive; Elem = char; Tr = std::char_traits<char>]’
/usr/include/boost/archive/detail/interface_oarchive.hpp:63:9:   required from ‘Archive& boost::archive::detail::interface_oarchive<Archive>::operator<<(T&) [with T = std::map<boost::uuids::uuid, void*>; Archive = boost::archive::binary_oarchive]’
graph.cpp:27:13:   required from here
/usr/include/boost/archive/detail/oserializer.hpp:465:27: error: ‘void*’ is not a pointer-to-object type
         register_type(ar, * t);
                           ^
/usr/include/boost/archive/detail/oserializer.hpp:473:18: error: ‘void*’ is not a pointer-to-object type
         save(ar, * t);
```

[**`See it on coliru`**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/50f478165ec1f357)

Answer (score 2):

That's correct. It does evaluate to the opaque integral type. This is by design and as documented.

`vecS` has contiguous storage, but `listS` and `setS` (etc) have iterator stability. You can pick what you need for your application.

This means you'll need an ID (BGL algorithms use the `vertex_index_t` property for that). Or, just use built-in serialization support.

```
#include <boost/archive/binary_oarchive.hpp>
#include <boost/graph/adj_list_serialize.hpp>
#include <boost/graph/adjacency_list.hpp>
#include <boost/uuid/uuid.hpp>
#include <boost/uuid/uuid_serialize.hpp>
#include <fstream>

typedef boost::adjacency_list<
    boost::listS, boost::listS, boost::bidirectionalS,
    boost::property<boost::vertex_index_t, boost::uuids::uuid>
> graph_type;

int main(){
    graph_type graph;

    std::ofstream stream("archive");
    boost::archive::binary_oarchive archive(stream);
    archive << graph;
}
```

Comment: Well I need to store a map of uuid and vertex index. So should I use `typedef std::map<boost::uuids::uuid, typename boost::graph_traits<graph_type>::vertex_descriptor> vertex_index_t;` instead ?

Comment: ?! Whoa. Why would naming the typedef make a difference (I mean, c++ has obscure features, but this ain't one of them)

Comment: Added a snippet that shows what I'd consider. Of course, there's a healthy dose of [X/Y problem](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) now that you've discovered that indeed what you wanted to do can't be done. Regardless, even if my suggestion isn't a direct hit, you'll need to think out of the box. You simply cannot use Boost Serialization to (usefully) serialize `void*`.

Comment: sorry I thought `boost::graph_traits<graph_type>::vertex_index_t` will work

Comment: But how will I create a `vertex_index` ? I need to `add_vertex` and store that in `std::map`. However add_vertex() returns vertex_descriptor only.

Comment: That would refer to the property map itself, not what you need. It's very simple, unless `std::map` is specialized for your vertex_descriptor type, it will not know how to deal with BGL

Comment: @NeelBasu Please consider not starting many rushed question with "but" "but". It takes time to read the documentation. Does this help http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/11fcd5232702f9b2

Comment: I've also use a bidirectional map (BiMap) in some [tag:boost-graph] answers before. That would give you more efficient lookup of vertex by uuid

Comment: Well, in actual implementation I've used a `vertex_property` class instead of using `boost::property`. So how will I use `boost::vertex_index_t` with my existing `vertex_property` class ? will I just add an `uuid` property there ? I am not working on a static graph. I'll be adding/removing vertices and edges dynamically, thats why I was useing an external `map`. With `boost::property` I believe there is no need to use an external `std::map`. However is it possible to use one ? or can you provide an example that uses an external `std::map` along with the graph ?

Comment: I'd be happy to look at the concrete usage pattern(s) you are trying to describe (as a new question?). These are too many questions with unclear context for me.

Comment: Yes posted http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32296206/bgl-indexing-a-vertex-by-keys