# BGL indexing a vertex by keys

Tags: c++, boost, boost-graph

My requirement is to have a graph structure where each vertex is uniquely identified by a `boost::uuids::uuid`. All vertices have a color property by which vertices of similar category will be grouped. I am not working on a static map, vertices and edges will be created and removed dynamically.

```
typedef boost::adjacency_list<
      boost::listS,
      boost::listS,
      boost::bidirectionalS,
      boost::property<boost::vertex_index_t, boost::uuids::uuid, 
        boost::property<boost::vertex_color_t, resource_color,
          boost::property<boost::vertex_underlying_t,   boost::shared_ptr<actual_object*> > > >,
      detail::edge_property
      > graph_type;
graph_type _graph;
boost::property_map<graph_type, boost::vertex_index_t>::type    _index_map;
boost::property_map<graph_type, boost::vertex_color_t>::type    _color_map;
boost::property_map<graph_type, boost::vertex_underlying_t>::type   _underlying_map;
```

In **constructor** I am creating all 3 maps

```
_index_map = boost::get(boost::vertex_index_t(), _graph);
_color_map = boost::get(boost::vertex_color_t(), _graph);
_underlying_map = boost::get(boost::vertex_underlying_t(), _graph);
```

while **adding** a vertex

```
add_resource(resource_color c, actual_object* o){
  graph_type::vertex_descriptor v = boost::add_vertex(o->uuid(), _graph);
  _color_map[v] = c;
  _underlying_map[v] = o;
}
```

For **list**ing UUID's of a vertex

```
uuid_list list;
boost::graph_traits<graph_type>::vertex_iterator vi, vi_end;
for(boost::tie(vi, vi_end) = boost::vertices(_graph); vi != vi_end; ++vi){
  list.push_back(_index_map[*vi]);
}
return list;
```

This way i am always iterating through vertices of the graph and getting its properties. However I want the other way too. From UUID to vertex like a parallel std::map which will be auto updated with add/remove operations or somethign similar.

Also I cannot keep an external `std::map` and sync manually, because `boost::adjacency_list<boost::listS, boost::listS>::vertex_descriptor` evaluates to `void*` and I need serialization support.

So is the following things doable

1. find vertex through `boost::vertex_index_t` value
2. iterate through a `boost::property_map`
3. synchronizing an external `std::map` or `bimap` with `index` property

Answer (score 3):

I remember the library has a `labeled_graph` utility that supports this roughly. It has a high convenience factor and I seem to remember it being less interesting in terms of efficiency¹. There should be a sample using it:

- http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_1/libs/graph/example/labeled_graph.cpp

Regardless (and referring back to your previous question) you can certainly use an external property map. This has benefits:

- you can keep entries that aren't in the graph at all times
- you can have the reverse index that you require, see e.g.

  - [Cut set of a graph, Boost Graph Library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26697477/cut-set-of-a-graph-boost-graph-library/26699982#26699982) (where it is used to get reverse-lookup of the colour map).

    > It also contains an equivalent approach but using Boost Multi-index Containers, which is much more flexible even

#### Answer bullets:

1. > find vertex through `boost::vertex_index_t` value

   Yes, but if you want to be efficient, indeed you need to either have an external mapping for the reverse lookup **OR** use your own datastructure and adapt it to [model the Graph Concepts you require](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_59_0/libs/graph/doc/graph_concepts.html) (much more work, obviously)
2. > iterate through a `boost::property_map`

   You can. Use `boost::get(tag, graph)` to get the property map, iterate across all entities you want to visit and invoke the property map for each property. E.g.

   ```
   boost::property_map<Graph, boost::vertex_index_t>::type pmap = boost::get(boost::vertex_index, graph);
   boost::graph_traits<Graph>::vertex_iterator b, e;
   for (boost::tie(b,e) = boost::vertices(graph); b!=e; ++b)
       std::cout << "The vertex ID is: " << boost::get(pmap, *b) << "\n";
   ```
3. > synchronizing an external `std::map` or `bimap` with `index` property

   The above links should give you ideas

---

¹ that would explain I haven't used it myself.

Comment: in (2) instead of iterating over `property_map` you are iterating over `vertices()`. I thought there will be a `multimap` kind of interface with `std::pair` like `value_type`
with (3) the problem is, to use a map I need something like `vertex_descriptor` to be stable. And for a stable `vertex_descriptor`  need to use `listS` instead of `vecS`. But with `listS`  `vertex_descriptor`   evaluates to `void*` I cannot understand this paradox. because If store `void*` in `std::map` it will not be seralizable. 
also there are other questions in SO that says `labeled_graph` is not serializable

Comment: in (1) what is the inefficient way of finding a vertex by `boost::vertex_index_t` ? linear search over `vertices()` (thats not finding vertex by index) ?

Comment: There is no paradox. Serializing vertex descriptors simply doesn't make sense unless they're the vertex id. If not, you -must- add a vertex id and use that. It simply always works that way. So, do what you usually do. when you're in a bind, program your way out of it. Here's my attempt live: https://www.livecoding.tv/sehe/

Comment: @NeelBasu I'm failing at getting this to work :( If I can get the overload resolution blocker to work, I'd continue. Right now it's 1:46am and I'm calling it quits :( (intermediate: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/9df3b2a25a185d20)

Comment: The short idea is to just have an external bimap (so you have your lookups). And for serialization just don't serialize the raw bimap but just build the bimap after loading the vertices with their properties.