# BGL: how can I get from a bundled object to a vertex descriptor?

Tags: c++, boost

The question is about the `Boost Graph Library` (there is no such label unfortunately).

Suppose that I have associated a `Widget` instance with each vertex of a graph by using the *bundled property* feature of the `Boost Graph Library`. The class `Widget` implements `operator==` and all widgets associated with vertices are distinct (i.e., for any pair of vertices, `widget1 != widget2` holds for the widgets associated with these vertices).

Does the graph maintain a *reverse* mapping, i.e. can I easily retrieve a vertex descriptor that corresponds to a given object? In particular, suppose that I have objects `widget1` and `widget2` and the corresponding vertices have been added into the graph. How can I add an edge between the two objects (i.e. between the corresponding vertices)?

Comment: Please have a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32296206/bgl-indexing-a-vertex-by-keys/32296688#32296688 the ***[Bimap suggestion](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26697477/cut-set-of-a-graph-boost-graph-library/26699982#26699982)*** could actually work for you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect that BGL itself cannot provide a mapping from a vertex attribute to the corresponding vertex descriptor because the mapping is `m:1` many to one, in general. Many vertices/descriptors can correspond to the same attribute. Even though in your case, you know that different vertices must have different attribute, BGL generally has no way of knowing that.

You can probably maintain this mapping (e.g. `vd_map`) yourself when you create the graph e.g. using `std:map`. When you insert each vertex with its attribute (`Widget` in this case), insert a corresponding entry:

```
vd_map[widget] = desc;
```

Comment: If I understand correctly, vertex descriptors can get invalidated. So, wouldn't this solution mean that I can never delete a vertex?

Comment: I am not sure what your code is trying to do. I guess if you need to delete a vertex, you can always delete the entry from this reverse lookup map beforehand.

Comment: You are right! If I use listS, then all is fine, since only one descriptor gets invalidated upon vertex deletion!